# Error when executing YeSQL query with a wrapped JDBC Connection by Hikari

Tags: jdbc, clojure

I am getting an error when trying to execute a sql query using YeSQL.

```
db-spec HikariProxyConnection wrapping org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection is missing a required parameter
```

I have defined a `find-by-id` function in my SQL file like this:

```
-- name: find-by-id
-- Selects the filepath to a menu by id
SELECT filepath FROM menu WHERE id = :id;
```

And I am calling the created function like this:

```
(find-by-id {:id "123"} {:connection (jdbc/get-connection {:datasource datasource)})
```

My datasource is defined like this:

```
(def spec {:maximum-pool-size  3
   :adapter            "postgresql"
   :username           "user"
   :database-name      "dbname"
   :server-name        "localhost"
   :port-number        5432})
(def datasource (make-datasource spec))
```

I can use the exact same connection map when passing it to `with-db-transaction` and using the returned connection, but for some reason it does not work like this.

Comment: Error message is pretty descriptive in this case: you pass raw connection object (not wrapped with `{:connection ...}`) to `jdbc/get-connection` somewhere.

Comment: I passed the datasource to like this `{:datasource datasource}` to `get-connection` which should be fine shouldn't it? It works fine if I use the returned object for `with-db-transaction`. In any case you were right I needed to wrap that in another `{:connection ...}`. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

To get a connection object with `jdbc/get-connection` that you can pass to a YeSQL query using a datasource, apparently you have to create it like this:

```
(defn get-connection
  [db]
  {:connection (jdbc/get-connection {:connection {:datasource datasource})})
```

Thank you for the help in the comments!